# LocalTime object - Add leading zero to the minutes

Tags: java, java-time, localtime, leading-zero

I am trying to create an object of the Java class `LocalTime` like this:

```
LocalTime beginning = LocalTime.of(int hours, int minutes);
```

My problem is that I would like that my user could input the time in the following format: HH:MM
However, when there's an input like 14:00 as String, I replace the ":" by "".

Then I say:

```
hours = Integer.parseInt(eingabe.substring(0, 2));
minutes = Integer.parseInt(eingabe.substring(2));
```

But now minutes is 0 and not 00 like I want it to.
I've done some research and found something like `String.format("%02d", minutes)`, but the parameters of `LocalTime.of()` needs to be integers.

Comment: hours and minutes can be stored as int, meaning that 0 is not 00. You only need that for an output, in that case, you can use the `String.format("%02d", minutes)` to get the string for the output, like you already researched.

Comment: Thank you
I also found out that the to.String() method gets me the output, which I wanted.

Comment: @CWhite that's not `to.String` , that is `.toString();`

Comment: Excuse me, thats what I meant

Answer (score 2):

If you have an input like `14:00` you don't need to do manual formatting, instead you can use [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
String input = "14:00";
DateTimeFormatter simpleTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime localtime = LocalTime.parse(input, simpleTime);
```

However your original problem was not a problem to begin with. The "00" in "14:00" is just formatting, it does not mean that the integer value of the minutes is `00`: it is `0`; it is just **displayed** as "00" to be less confusing for people viewing the time (eg it is hard to distinguish `14:1` from `14:10` etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can not get a int with double zero because it is an integer value, the only way to get a double zero is formatting your LocalTime to String. There are different ways to do this and it depends in the Date API that your are using. Seeing your classes I assume that your are using JodaTime, so my example will be focused to this API, so, to format your object, you can do this:

```
public static String toTimeString(LocalTime source) {

    try {
        return source.toString("HH.mm");
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    return null;
}
```